# Norm in the space of absolutely convergent Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, normed-spaces, wiener-algebra

In the book *Ensemble parfaits et séries trigonométriques*, Kahane and Salem assert the following :

> $\big\|\exp\big(ing(x)\big)\big\|_{A(\mathbb{T})}$ is $O(|n|)$ where $g \in C^\infty(\mathbb{T})$ **is real-valued** and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Here the $A(\mathbb{T})$-norm is of course the norm of the Wiener algebra of functions with absolutely convergent Fourier series.

How come this norm is $O(|n|)$ ?

Comment: The $C^1$-norm of $\exp\big(ing(x)\big)$ is $O(|n|)$. Could this be of any use here ?

Comment: A typo I meant $\mathcal{O}(k^2)$, and I'm not sure how you can improve it to $\mathcal{O}(k)$

Comment: To be clear, $g(x)$ is real ? In that case the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product could help

Comment: I couldn't find any indication that $g(x)$ is real but Kahane & Salem are merely  explaining a proof by Kaufman. I just had a look to the article of Kaufman and he states that $g(x)$ is indeed real-valued.

Comment: Take $g(x) = -i$, then $c_0(e^{i k g(x)}) = 2\pi e^k$ so yes obviously $Im(g(x)) \ge 0$

Comment: tell me if you find the answer

Comment: @M.G I see that you have created ([tag:wiener-algebra]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/wiener-algebra/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. (This is probably not a problem here, since the tag name seems to be descriptive enough.) Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless they have tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).

Comment: @Martin Sleziak I'll do that. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: I am a bit surprised to see that your [suggested edit was rejected](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/729534). While in theory I agree with the reason described there, in this case the name of the tag seem unambiguous enough to me. I wen ahead and edited it with the text from your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your claim is not true if $Im(g(x)) < 0$, in that case it grows exponentially. And if $Im(g(x))\ge 0$ I find $\mathcal{O}(k^2)$ :*

$$\|f\|_{A(\mathbb{T})}= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |c_n(f)|, \qquad \qquad c_n(f) = \int_0^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-i n x}dx$$

Also note that $$c_n(f')=i n c_n(f), \qquad\qquad c_n(f'')=-n^2 c_n(f)$$
With $G_k(x) = e^{ik g(x)}$ we have $G_k'(x) = ik g'(x)G_k(x)$ and $G_k''(x) = ik g''(x)G_k(x)-k^2g'(x)^2 G_k(x)$.

Assuming $Im(g(x))\ge 0$ we have $|G_k(x)|,|g(x)|,|g'(x)|,|g''(x)|$ bounded by a constant $\beta$, so that $|G_k''(x)|<k^2 \beta_2$,

and for $n \ne 0$ :
$$|c_n(G_k)| = \frac{|c_n(G_k'')|}{ n^2} \le \frac{ k^2 \beta_2}{n^2}$$
with 
i.e.

$$\|G_k\|_{A(\mathbb{T})} = |c_1(G_K)|+\sum_{n\ne 0} |c_n(G_k)| \le 2\pi\beta+2\pi k^2 \beta_2\sum_{n\ne 0} \frac{1}{n^2}= \mathcal{O}(k^2)$$